# How to set Date format in Excel using perl script?

Tags: excel, perl, date, formatting

We have requirement to set the cell format as date in excel, So can someone please help to achieve this through perl.

Please refer the attachment that show how the cell format should be.

[image]

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: Excel::Writer::XLSX

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#write_date_time(_$row,_$col,_$date_string,_$format_))

Comment: Hi, We have tried this "Write_date_time" function by setting the input format as 'mm/dd/yyyy', But in excel it is showing as custom format instead of date format, Can you please let us know if there is any function which will convert the input date as date format as mention in the previously attached screen shot.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to set that using Excel::Writer::XLSX. You can look at the module Win32::OLE for this, it may be useful as it has all the methods like VBA.

Comment: Hi Mohit, Can you please share the link to download the WIN32::OLE package, Also can you please provide us the sample example for the same.

Comment: Can you please let me know the alternate approach without installing this package (WIN32::OLE).

Comment: WIN32::OLE package is built in for windows OS, Can anyone please let me know is there is any package or WIN32::OLE for AIX, which will resolve this issue and that package need to support for AIX, I have been searching to resolve this for a long time, So can someone please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.